# Group by only returns one row

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using the following sql in mySQL.
I don't understand why I get only one row as output.

```
select category, count(*) as counts  
 from table_1   
where  date_add between '2016-07-01' and '2016-07-31'  
group by category
```

Comment: this coulld mean that for the dates  range is selected only one category .. try check the data

Comment: Because for that date range, there might be single category

Comment: How many rows did you expect, i.e. how many different categories can be found during that period?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How many `categories` do you have in that date range would be the first thing you'd have to look for since you're grouping by `categories`. If you have 'n' number of `categories` **within the specified date period**, ideally you result set should have 'n' rows.

There is nothing wrong with your query per se. I tried the query with two categories and I do get the expected result set.

If you want all the categories in the result set irrespective of whether they are in the result set or not, then you can something of this sort :

```
select      category, count(*) as counts
from        tab
where       date_add between '2016-07-01' and '2016-07-31'  
group by    category

union

select      category, 0 as counts
from        tab
where       date_add not between '2016-07-01' and '2016-07-31'  
group by    category
```

*Mind you this is a simple way of doing this but certainly not the best*

This will show all the categories irrespective of the date peroids. You can see this here -> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a3a9b/2
See this here -> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bdb979/1

If you modify the data set in the fiddle to have three categories, then again, the result set returns the expected 3 rows.

See this here -> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ec7a8/1

Again, its important to note that the categories have to be present within that date period for them to show up in the result set.

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

Just do some changes and try :

```
select category, count(*) as counts  
 from table_1   
group by category
```

Use above code and see if it return more than one row , it means that you query is correct but only one row is matching below criteria ie:

```
where  date_add between '2016-07-01' and '2016-07-31'  
group by category
```

So Query returning one row, when your database table will have more data match this criteria  htne it will return more row. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are clearly only getting one row because only one category matches the `where` condition.

If you want all categories with the count of adds in that range, then use conditional aggregation:

```
select category,
       sum(date_add between '2016-07-01' and '2016-07-31') as counts  
from table_1   
group by category;
```